# Django. How Q() really works?

Tags: django, django-models, django-q

in my database there is a table that holds some user information. The table is called `UserBalance` and fields include `user`, `credits_in` and `credits_out` and `remark` (among others)

I am trying to sum the `credits_in` for a certain user but I get different sums for different cases. Take a look at this:

```
>>> cg = UserBalance.objects.filter(user=ranked_user).filter(remark__icontains='credits g').aggregate(sum_in=Sum('credits_in'))
>>> cg
{'sum_in': 35.85}
>>> cg = UserBalance.objects.filter(user=ranked_user).filter(Q(remark='credits gained') or Q(remark='credits given')).aggregate(sum_in=Sum('credits_in'))
>>> cg
{'sum_in': 26.16}
>>> cg = UserBalance.objects.filter(user=ranked_user).filter(Q(remark='credits given') or Q(remark='credits gained')).aggregate(sum_in=Sum('credits_in'))
>>> cg
{'sum_in': 9.69}
```

in the first case I used `i_cointains`, in the second and third cases I use a Q() but with its terms switched.

Can someone explain what is the difference between the 2nd and the 3rd case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `(Q(remark='credits gained')|Q(remark='credits given'))`, not`(Q(remark='credits gained') or Q(remark='credits given'))`

It's 2 completely different operators:
| is bitwise OR, but it's overriden for Q():

```
def __or__(self, other):
    return self._combine(other, self.OR)
```

while `or` is logical (or rather 'coalescing') operator. It means that `Q(remark='credits gained') or Q(remark='credits given')` will return first not-None object, that's why in your second case it will result in `Q(remark='credits gained')`, and in the third one - in `Q(remark='credits given')`